# Camera Image format/extension (iOS/android/windows)

Tags: image, camera, format, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Just a doubt about camera pictures (iOS/android/windows)

```
//take a picture
Ti.Media.showCamera({
    saveToPhotoGallery:false,
    success:function(event) {

        if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {

            $.preview.image = event.media;

            //insert on attachments table
            database.insert('attachments',{
                name:'test',
                extension:'',
                file:Ti.Utils.base64encode(event.media).toString()
            });
        }
    }
});
```

When I send the picture to my backoffice, I need to send also the file extension, but there is no file, only the string of the encoded picture that I saved in a local SQLite table.

How do I get this extension, or it's required to save the image on the app directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set any image extension you want ! (PNG, jPEG ,..) , as you see data returned from camera is `Blob` ! , you don`t have to save the image local first just upload it to your server !

Comment: Thanks, just one more thing, when I run any SQLite query I log it to the console, in this case, the log of the encoded image converted to string has \n on the beginning of every line, this is right or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: \nUAUEAEaBAAECBAgkExAAJGu4cgkQIECAQBUQABgFAgQIECCQTEAAkKzhyiVAgAABAlVAAGAU
\nCBAgQIBAMgEBQLKGK5cAAQIECFQBAYBRIECAAAECyQQEAMkarlwCBAgQIFAFBABGgQABAgQI
\nJBMQACRruHIJECBAgEAVEAAYBQIECBAgkExAAJCs4colQIAAAQJVQABgFAgQIECAQDIBAUCy
\nhiuXAAECBAhUAQGAUSBAgAABAskEBADJGq5cAgQIECBQBQQARoEAAQIECCQTEAAka7hyCRAg
\nQIBAFRAAGAUCBAgQIJBMQACQrOHKJUCAAAECVUAAYBQIECBAgEAyAQFAsoYrlwABAgQIVAEB
\ngFEgQIAAAQLJBAQAyRquXAIECBAgUAUEAEaBAAECBAgkExAAJGu4cgkQIECAQBUQABgFAgQI
\nECCQTEAAkKzhyiVAgAABAlVAAGAUCBAgQIBAMgEBQLKGK5cAAQIECFQBAYBRIECAAAECyQQE
\nAMkarlwCBAgQIFAFBABGgQABAgQIJBMQACRruHIJECBAgEAVEAAYBQIECBAgkExAAJCs4col

Comment: solved with: img = img.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");